# Is a dispatch_group_notify block persistant for the lifespan of a dispatch_group_t?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

If I have a `dispatch_group` class property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_group_t _serialGroup;
```

and I have a block that I *always* want called whenever the group completes:

```
dispatch_group_notify(self._serialGroup, self._serialQueue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //...do some stuff...
    });
});
```

Can I just define the `dispatch_group_notify` upon initilization of the `dispatch_group` once and it'll be called whenever that group completes or do I need to redefine it every time I add items to the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dispatch_group_notify()` block gets submitted exactly once to the specified queue the first time the group becomes empty after the API is called (or immediately if the group is already empty).

If you want a notification block to be invoked again, you must reinstall it (e.g. as part of the notification block itself, but be aware that it will be re-submitted right away if the group is still empty when you reinstall it).

Comment: Dang, the use case here is I want a `block()` to be called when a queue is empty but I'm constantly adding items to the queue so how do I make sure the `block()` is added w/out adding it multiple times?

Comment: I can't think of a clean & cheap way to do that with the current group API (but it would be a worthwhile enhancement request to file...). Your easiest efficient option is probably to replace your calls to `dispatch_group_async()` with your own `dispatch_async()` wrapper that maintains an atomic counter via `OSAtomicIncrement()`/`OSAtomicDecrement()` and triggers a `dispatch_async()` of your notification block at the 1->0 transition (i.e. when decrement returns 0).

Answer (score 0):

you have to release it yourself by calling dispatch_release().  So you could hold onto it till and reuse it

Comment: I have to call `dispatch_release` on  my `dispatch_group` yes but the question is can I just define a notification block once on creation or is the notification block called on completion and then released.  Such that defining the block right after group creation effectively does nothing.